# Select with React.JS - dynamically populated options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am trying to populate select in [stateless component of] React/Redux app as:

```
const FillSelect = ({team}) => <option value={team.onboardingOrder}>{team.name}</option>

const TeamSelector = ({teams}) => {
  return (
    <select>
      <option value="">All</option>
      {
        teams ? (teams => teams.map(team => <FillSelect team={team} />)) : null
      }
    </select>
  )
}
```

Teams looks like:`{0:{id: 1, name: "Program Management", onboardingOrder: 0, …}, 1: {id: 2, name: "Value Capture", onboardingOrder: 1, …}…}`.

It returns an error: `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in select ...`

Is this happening because I am using `map()`? What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Also, you can't `map` an object. Use `Object.values(teams).map...`

Comment: One cannot `map` ANY object, but iterables are supported, right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
  return (
    <select>
      <option value="">All</option>
      {
        Object.values(teams).map((team, i) => <option value={team.onboardingOrder} key={i}>{team.name}</option> )
      }
    </select>
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling map directly; if `teams` is truthy, you return a function (`teams => ...`). You probably wanted the line to look like this:

```
teams ? teams.map(team => <FillSelect team={team} />) : null
```

Which would yield an array of `<FillSelect />`'s.

Comment: Did not make any difference.